# Setting MatrixWorld of camera in threeJS

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to sync the camera orientation of one threejs scene with another by passing the world matrix of the first scene's camera to the second and then using

```
         camera.matrix.fromArray(cam1array); //cam1array is the flattened worldmatrix of the 1st scene
         camera.updateMatrixWorld( true );
```

However, when I print camera.matrixWorld for the second scene, it would appear that there has been no update (matrixWorld is the same as before the previous commands). The second scene does use OrbitControls so maybe they are overriding my commands, but I wondered if anyone could advise me on how to achieve the same world matrix for the second scene as the first?

I should also clarify that part of the issue is that it would appear that setting
camera.matrixAutoUpdate = false;

in order to prevent overriding seems to prevent OrbitControls from functioning corrrectly.

Comment: `Matrix4.fromArray()` takes an array as input, not a matrix object. Though presumably, that is not the main issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Yeah the variable name is confusing - I edited the code snippet to make it clear that the argument of fromArray is the flattened world matrix (i.e. an array).

Comment: Right, yes I suppose `matrixAutoUpdate` would need to be set to false if you intend to update the matrix directly. You could of course copy the camera's orientation or position instead of the entire matrix, if that's the only thing that has changed. If you really need to update the matrix directly, then I am not sure how to best solve it.